# How do i find number of objects in list in Python

Tags: python

For example, list[1, 2, 3] has 3 items (and indexex 0, 1, 2).

How can I print the number of objects in a list? In this istance, it would be "3".

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0):

use `len` :

```
 >> lst = [0,1,2,3]
 >> len(lst)
 4
```

Note : never use `list` as a variable name.